# get woocommerce My account page link

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to send an email to customer after purchased products and when customer click on the the link provided the email for rating the product it should redirect to customer's account/My account page.
I put some code in functions.php to get the WooCommerce My Account URL:

```
$myaccount_page = get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' );
if ( $myaccount_page ) {
  $myaccount_page_url = get_permalink( $myaccount_page );
  }
```

I have customized into **customer-completed-order.php** and put this code

```
    <h2> Go to your account page for review </h2>
    <a href="http://animax.cf/product/happy-ninja/#reviews">
        <img src="http://animax.cf/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/product-reviews.png" alt="Product Rating">
    </a>
```

I want to get woocomerce myaccount url in above code. how should i do this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can get the WooCommerce my-account URL as below

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ); ?>" title="<?php _e('My Account',''); ?>"><?php _e('My Account',''); ?></a>
```

Now you can insert this in completed order mail template too.

```
<h2> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ); ?>" title="<?php _e('My Account',''); ?>">Go to your account page for review</a> </h2>
<a href="http://animax.cf/product/happy-ninja/#reviews">
    <img src="http://animax.cf/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/product-reviews.png" alt="Product Rating">
</a>
```

Comment: Actually i am beginner in php and wordpress. So, thank you very much WPTC-Troop.

Comment: Instead of using `get_option` and `get_permalink`, just use WC's function for this: `wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' )`

Answer (score 20):

woocommerce  wc_get_page_id function will help you to create WooCommerce pages URLs

Examples of usage:

My Account

```
<?php echo get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ); ?>
```

Shop

```
<?php echo get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 7):

There is another way to do this using the WooCommerce native endpoints (you can use any of the registered endpoints with WC or third-party plugins that hook into WC):
`<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_account_endpoint_url( 'edit-account' ) ); ?>`

For dashboard you could use something like this
`<?php echo esc_url( trailingslashit( wc_get_account_endpoint_url( '' ) ) ); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

It returns account page itself without endpoints:

```php
echo wc_get_account_endpoint_url('dashboard');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
     <?php  
       if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
        // Default homepage
        echo "Default homepage";

        } elseif ( is_front_page()){

            echo "Static homepage";
        // Static homepage

        } elseif ( is_home()){
            echo "Blog page";
        // Blog page

        } elseif ( is_page( 'cart' ) || is_cart()){
            echo "cart";
        // Blog page

        }  elseif (is_single()){
            echo "is_single";
        // Blog page

        } elseif (is_product_category()){
            echo "is_product_category";
        } 
         else {
        echo "Everything else";
        // Everything else
        }
      ?>
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?